# Deleting millions of rows from a MSSQL server table

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server, time-limit-exceeded

This SQL query took 38 minutes to delete just 10K of rows. How can I optimize it?

Index already exists for `CREATEDATE` from `table2`.

```
declare @tmpcount int
declare @counter int

SET @counter = 0
SET @tmpcount = 1
WHILE @counter <> @tmpcount
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 10000

    SET @counter = @counter + 1

    DELETE table1
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2
        ON table2.DOC_NUMBER = table1.DOC_NUMBER
        AND table2.DOC_YEAR = table1.DOC_YEAR
    WHERE YEAR(CREATEDDATE) BETWEEN 2007 and 2009

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
        BREAK
END
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The performance problem is due to the non-sargable expression `YEAR(CREATEDATE)`.  Applying a function to a column in a WHERE clause prevents efficient use of the index on the column.  Below is an alternative technique, which uses an inclusive start and exclusive end for the datetime range.

Note the use of `SET ROWCOUNT` is deprecated for `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.  Use `TOP` instead.

```
DELETE TOP(10000) table1
FROM dbo.table1
JOIN dbo.table2
    ON table2.DOC_NUMBER = table1.DOC_NUMBER
    AND table2.DOC_YEAR = table1.DOC_YEAR
WHERE 
    CREATEDDATE >= '20070101' 
    AND CREATEDATE < '20100101';
```

I'm not sure the purpose of @tmpcount in your script other than perhaps controlling the number of iterations for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Besides great performance improvement due to `Dan`'s suggestion, the code can also be improved. I have put comments to indicate changes:

```
-- contract declaration and assignment
declare @tmpcount int = 1
declare @counter int = 1

-- this can be declared before the cycle, as it is not changes within the cycle
SET ROWCOUNT 10000

-- @@ROWCOUNT will be 1 due to last assignment
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND @counter <> @tmpcount)
BEGIN
    SET @counter = @counter + 1

    DELETE table1
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2
        ON table2.DOC_NUMBER = table1.DOC_NUMBER
        AND table2.DOC_YEAR = table1.DOC_YEAR
    WHERE YEAR(CREATEDDATE) BETWEEN 2007 and 2009

    -- break condition was moved in while
    -- it works as long as DELETE remains the last instruction in the while
END
```